# Prompt for number - if not a number or if a decimal point, prompt for new number and convert to number

Tags: javascript

I need to make a prompt that asks for a number and then convert that string into a number. If they do not enter a number, I need to prompt again for a number and convert the string that they enter into a number. If they enter a decimal number, I need to prompt for an integer and convert the string into a number.

I thought that I could use the same variable name for all, but to get it to work, I needed to define different variables for the two other prompts. Why is this? How can I get it down so that when calling functions, I can just reference one variable instead of three?

Here is my code:

```
var numSubmit = prompt("Please enter a number");

    if(isNaN(numSubmit)) {
        var newNum = prompt("A number is required.");
        newNum = +newNum;
        // Why did I need to define a new variable in order to convert it to a number? Why didn't keeping the original variable and writing numSubmit = +numSubmit work?
    }
    else if (numSubmit % 1 != 0) {
        var noDecimal = prompt("Please do not enter a decimal number.");
        noDecimal = +noDecimal;
    }
    else {
        numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
```

My original code was this:

```
var numSubmit = prompt("Please enter a number");

    if(isNaN(numSubmit)) {
         prompt("A number is required.");
         numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
    else if (numSubmit % 1 != 0) {
         prompt("Please do not enter a decimal number.");
         numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
    else {
        numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
```

When I entered a letter, and got the message that a number is required, and then entered a number, the result came back as NaN.

Edited to add:

This seems to work:

```
var numSubmit = prompt("Please enter a number");

while(isNaN(numSubmit)) {
    numSubmit = prompt("A number is required")
}

while(numSubmit % 1 != 0) {
    numSubmit = prompt("Please do not enter a decimal number.");
}

numSubmit = +numSubmit;
```

Comment: You don't need a different variable. What issue did you encounter that made you think you do?

Comment: I edited my question to add the original code.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm understanding your issue. You're not capturing the value of the new `prompt()`. I assumed you were running this in a loop, which you should be so that the validation can be applied to each new value.

Comment: Would it be a while loop? I'm just learning about loops and from my understanding, you use a for loop when you know how many times you want the loop to run.

Comment: You don't need a new variable, but you do need to put `numSubmit = ` before every prompt, otherwise the value entered in the prompt isn't stored anywhere

Comment: @amylynn83: In this case, since you don't know how many times it will need to run, you'd just use `while (true) {...` and then use `break` when they finally give a valid input. http://jsfiddle.net/uD8an/

Comment: Although, then the next line `numSubmit = +numSubmit;` is pretty useless, and that's probably why you do need a new var

Comment: I think I got it now. I added while loops for non-numbers and decimals and added the conversion to the bottom so that it converts the string into a number after those loops have run. I will add the new code into my question.

Comment: Your `while` solution won't really work. It assumes that a person will always make the same error multiple times. If they enter `"a"`, then `"1.23"` then `"a"` again, it'll fail. What you need is to put your original `if/else if/else` inside the loop like I showed in the jsFiddle demo.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the jfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you didn't assign numSubmit to the values of the second and third prompts in your code.

You need to add `numSubmit =` before `prompt("Please enter a number")` and `prompt("Please do not enter a decimal number.")`

This is what your code should look like:

```
var numSubmit = prompt("Please enter a number");

    if(isNaN(numSubmit)) {
         numSubmit = prompt("A number is required.");
         numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
    else if (numSubmit % 1 != 0) {
         numSubmit = prompt("Please do not enter a decimal number.");
         numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
    else {
        numSubmit = +numSubmit;
    }
```